# Force reload of a page after a specific redirection in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website on WordPress, this website use Ajax Page load. I have a login form (with theme my login) for my visitors and some are in trouble when login using Firefox. They need to refresh manually their page after login to see the features reserved for subscribers.

I use that code in my functions.php to redirect my visitors after login on home :

```
add_filter("login_redirect", "gkp_subscriber_login_redirect", 10, 3);
function gkp_subscriber_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user) {

  if(is_array($user->roles))
      if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) return site_url('/wp-admin/');

  return home_url();
}
```

I would like that the redirection to homepage also force a refresh of the page after the connexion. Is it possible ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

It refreshes your current page, and if you want to redirect it to another page, use following:

```
header("Refresh:0; url=something.php");
```